# Setting up PhoneGap on Eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, cordova

I've been following tutorials to set up a PhoneGap project (Android) on Eclipse, I'm fairly new to JS frameworks so I'm setting it up to start learning how to use them. In the tutorial (and any other I watch), they use an older version of PhoneGap that includes a .jar file and that isn't present with the latest version. I'm guessing it will still be easy to do but I'm just missing something obvious.

Is there another way to set it up now? Or do I simply not need this file? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

[The Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) specifically shows how to open up the project in Eclipse.

> Use the cordova utility to set up a new project, as described in The Cordova The Command-Line Interface. For example, in a source-code directory:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build
```

> - Launch the Eclipse Application.
> - Select New Project menu item.
> - Choose Android Project from Existing Code from the resulting dialog box, and press Next:
> - Navigate to `hello`, or whichever directory you created for the project, then to the `platforms/android` subdirectory.
> - Make sure both hello and hello-CordovaLib projects are selected to be imported. **The hello-CordovaLib project is needed as of Cordova 3.3.0 because Cordova is now used as an Android Library instead of a .jar file**
> - Press Finish.

This is all in the documentation.